# installing apc on php on OS X

Tags: php, macos, apc, pecl

I recently just upgraded my PHP version to 5.4.6, before I had APC installed and working just fine. But now APC is no longer there. I have added the `extension="apc.so"` to the php.ini file and restarted the web server, but I still can't see it there. Doing pecl install apc
gives me:

```
pecl install apc
pecl/apc is already installed and is the same as the  released version 3.1.9
```

says that it has been installed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you upgrade PHP to 5.4.6? Did you try http://php-osx.liip.ch/? Comes with a recent APC

Or try

```
pecl install --force apc
```